# Why the value of the key is not changed after I made some change in the for loop

Tags: python

I have a dictionary variable OutputFrames, and I tried to fill NaN with ffill and bfill method `df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method='bill')`. It shows the right result when I am printing it in the for loop. But When I check the dictionary using the key, it shows nothing changed.
Anybody knows why?

I also tried

`chartFrame.fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True).fillna(method='bfill', inlace = True)`

because there is one column(**SBT**) filled with none in the value of the key, so it also doesn't work --- `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'`.

You can see this from the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please post actual data, not pictures!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `chartFrame = chartFrame.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method='bill')` inside a for loop you are not actually changing the the dataframe in `OutputFrames`. You are just assining it to the variable `chartFrame`. Printing that variable shows the right result but it is not stored.

Either reassign the frame at the current key (preferred):

```
OutputFrames[key] = chartFrame.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
```

Or use `inplace=True` without chaining the operation. When you do an inplace operation the dataframe is changed in place and nothing is returned. This basically results in `None.nafill()` which causes the mentioned error.

```
chartFrame.fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
chartFrame.fillna(method='bfill', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Super helpful and very clear explanation. Thank you!